# Snap scrolling and Render times in ReactJS Causing Browser to Start at Wrong Place

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

### Problem

I have three components that each take up a fullscreen in my HomePage.js and are stacked one on top of each other vertically. I am using snap-scrolling to go between the three components. The first two components do API calls while the last one does not. I realized that the third component is rendering first since it has no API calls, but then the other two component that load after render on top of it. Specifically, the third component renders first, then the browser stays at that third components while the other two components render above leaving my HomePage view in the wrong order on an initial render.

### Question

Do I need to use some kind of isLoaded state variable to keep track of the components rendering or can I control the scroll position? What's a good solution for this? How do people normally control the order of rendering? Also, as I mentioned earlier, I know that rendering order has to do with the issue because without snap scrolling the third component will quickly flash on the screen before being shoved down to the bottom (the browser does correctly stay at the top of the page though). I feel like there should be a better way to control the order of rendering of components!

### Code

Currently my HomePage.js looks like this (my app is a song app)

```
return(
    <div className="home">
        <CurrentlyPlayingSection className="section" song={currentlyPlayingSong}/>
        <RecommendedSection className="section" song={recommendedSong}/>
        <LyricsSection className="section" song={currentlyPlayingSong}/>
    </div>
);
```

My styling for home:

```
.home {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
```

My styling for each section:

```
.section {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

This is my first web dev project, so please let me know if my code, especially the CSS, is repetitive or illogical.